# chrome.tabs.sendMessage callback function is not called. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have the following method that is called from the *background script* of my Chrome Extension. The goal is to send a message to a specific tab and then call provided callback method with the result. The important part is that the `callbackDone` must be **always** called at some point in time. So it goes as such:

```
function sendToTab(nTabID, callbackDone)
{
    (function()
    {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(nTabID, {
            action: "update01"
        }, 
        function(response) 
        {
            if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
            {
                //Failed to send message to the page
                if(callbackDone)
                    callbackDone(nTabID, null); //Page never received the message
            }
            else
            {
                //Sent message OK
                if(response.result === true)
                {
                    if(callbackDone)
                        callbackDone(nTabID, true); //Success!
                }
                else
                {
                    if(callbackDone)
                        callbackDone(nTabID, false);    //Page returns failure
                }
            }
        });
    }());
}
```

Then from within the page that processes the message (can be an injected `content script`) I handle it as such:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageProc);

function onMessageProc(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if(request.action == "update01")
    {
        //Do processing .... that sets `bResult`

        sendResponse({result: bResult});
    }
}
```

The above approach works quite well, except... Say, there's a page, like *Options page script*, that does not process my `update01` message and instead, it processes its own message as such:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageProc);

function onMessageProc(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if(request.action == "update02")   //Note different action ID
    {
        //Does some other actions...
    }
}
```

In this case when my first `sendToTab` method is called for this tab, my `callbackDone` is never called, i.e. `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` is invoked and it returns immediately but its callback function is never called.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think that's all relevant code.

Comment: @Xan: What are you talking about?

Comment: I thought it's important what's in your listeners. It is, but your code snippet is sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing expected behavior.

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) states, regarding the callback function:

> If you specify the responseCallback parameter, it should be a function that looks like this:
>
> `function(any response) {...};`
>
> `any  response`
> The JSON response object sent by the handler of the message. If an error occurs while connecting to the specified tab, the callback will be called with no arguments and `runtime.lastError` will be set to the error message.

There are 3 possible results of `sendMessage` executing.

1. There was a listener, and it called `sendResponse`.
   Then, the callback is called with the response as a parameter.
2. There was a listener, and it terminated without calling `sendResponse` (synchronously or asynchronously).
   Then, **the callback is not called at all**.
3. There was some sort of error sending the message.
   Then, the callback is called with no arguments and `chrome.runtime.lastError` set.

If you need your callback to execute in any circumstance, you'll need a "default" case in your listeners that calls `sendResponse`.

Comment: Thanks. Although it would really help if your 3 points were included in the documentation. Or at least it would eliminate bugs and confusion... How do you know all this?

Comment: In this case, I just tested it. Then, cross-referenced with documentation, and the quote above can be interpreted like this.

Comment: @c00000fd You're not calling your `sendResponse`, and wondering why the `response` function is never called?  Seems like expected behavior to me.

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't know. I would expect the callback to be called without arguments and with unset `chrome.runtime.lastError`. I suppose c00000fd did, too.